# AMD xop check support

Tags: c, gcc, amd-processor, xop

I have next problem:
I have some tests related to xop check with using some `Bulldozer (xop)` instructions.
And I must run this tests only on `Bulldozer` processors.
How can I check that my processor supports `xop` instruction at compile-time?

*Language:* `C`, *Os:* `Linux`;

Comment: You mean you want to check if the machine you are compiling on has XOP?

Comment: @Mysticial yes but at compile-time (not run-time)

Comment: You will need a USB crystal ball in order to determine at compile-time what the CPU will eventually be at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test at compile time, but you can compile for AMD Bulldozer using:

> $ gcc -march=bdver1 -mtune=bdver1 ...

See: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html

If your build machine is your target machine, look into `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program that checks CPUID and use the output of that program while compiling:
`gcc $(cpuid_test) my_prog.c`

where cpuid_test returns `'-march=bdver1'` or `-DXOP_SUPPORT=1`

Answer (score 0):

If a source is compiled with `-march=bdver1` (which enables XOP support among other things), the preprocessor macro `__XOP__` will be defined to 1.

You can test at compile time for XOP with

```
#ifdef __XOP__
     ...XOP code path here...
#else
     ...non XOP code here...
#endif
```